# Cordova create project not working

Tags: cordova

I am noob in cordova. Just installed it on my system. 
Whenever I do

```
cordova create testApp
```

it goes to next line without any output.
Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Are you getting testApp directory created in your disk

Comment: Are you able to see Creating a new Cordova Project

Comment: no it was not created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all thanks for the answers.
The problem was with node versions, once I setup the correct node version it started working.

```
nvm use
```

Answer (score 0):

The create command creates the required directory structure for your cordova app. It will not give any output. You have to add platform, build and run the app to expect an output. I strongly recommend you to have a look at this [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/) to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for creating cordova project is :

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

The first argument `hello` specifies a directory to be generated for your project

The second argument `com.example.hello` provides your project with a reverse domain-style identifier.

The third argument `HelloWorld` provides the application's display title.

For detailed information you can visit :
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html